# How do I disassemble AMD ELF?

Tags: disassembly

I tried to disassemble AMD ELF by using objdump.
But objdump say 'File format not recognized'.
How do I disassemble AMD ELF on x86 os?

Comment: Try to provide MUCH more info. See answer below

Comment: First you can use 'readelf' tool for help information, then write the python capstone script to disassembly it.

Comment: AMD ELF makes no sense. Neither does "x86 os"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this tool, http://www.onlinedisassembler.com/odaweb/file_upload, to disassemble a file for almost any architecture.

Answer (score 4):

Are you talking about an AMD64, a.k.a. x86_64, binary? What kind of OS are you running? I'm assuming Linux since you are using 'objdump', but perhaps another UNIX variant? What type of CPU? If you are on Linux, please run 'uname -a' and post the results in this question. Also, what distribution ('cat /etc/issue' to find out)?

My best guess is that you are running a 32-bit x86 Linux distribution that does not have support for x86_64 binaries (I just tried to disassemble an x86_64 binary on my x86_32 Ubuntu 11.04 distro and it worked fine).